# Implicit type in lambda capture

Tags: c++

I'm starting out with C++ programming, and am curious why this is legal:

```
auto myFun = [n=0]() mutable {return n++;};
```

I would have thought this wouldn't work, as C++ is a strong typed language, but it seems that the compiler infers the integer type?

Comment: A language can be strongly typed *and* infer types - these two concepts are not mutually exclusive

Comment: C++ compilers are getting smarter all the time. I think this is intended to offset the Idiocracy Effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas, were introduced with C++11. There were no default initializer values in C++11:

```
auto myFun = [n]() { /* body */ };
```

That's all you had in C++11. Whatever the type of `n` was, that's what you captured, type and value.

Default initialization values were introduced with C++14. I suppose that it would've been possible to change the syntax so that the initialized captured variables used a complete, full-fledged declaration, something like:

```
auto myFun = [int n=0]() mutable {return n++;};
```

That might've been possible, but this wasn't really necessary. Even though C++14's default capture values do not explicitly state their types, their types are inferred from their initialization expressions just as strongly as if they were explicitly declared. And the resulting change in syntax is minimal. With:

```
auto myFun = [n=0]() mutable {return n++;};
```

the type of `n` is `int`, just as "strong" as if it were explicitly declared. It is not a `char`, and it is not a `short`. It is an `int`. End of story.

Also, keep in mind that with:

```
template<typename Arg> void function(Arg arg)
```

when this is invoked the type of `Arg` gets deduced, and it becomes a bone-fide, strong type, too. So this is really no different than template parameters: in the end when instantiated their types are still as strong as they are in the rest of C++.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. My second question was going to be "why isn't this possible:  int n = 0" but you explained that via the changes from 11 to 14, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

From the reference on [lambda captures](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture):

> A capture with an initializer acts as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable declared with type auto, ...

This means the `[n = 0]` is basically treated as if it's

```
auto n = 0;
```

The placeholder type is deduced by the compiler as `int`, and the same type inference happens in the lambda capture.

This convenient syntax of not needing to say `auto` in the initializer of a lambda capture is just that, a convenience. This syntax doesn't result in any changes to the type safety imposed by the language.